# Microsoft Graph API: Sending emails bounce

Tags: php, email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using this library [msgraph-sdk-php](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php) and have a PHP script to send emails from my Outlook account but I keep getting this error:

```
Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:

12345@gmail.com
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.


Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: aaaaaa.namprd20.prod.outlook.com

berner@teamarmando.com
Remote server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=1111 AS(7230) [aaaaaa.namprd20.prod.outlook.com 2023-07-10T18:12:42.295Z 08DB80CBA17B93D4]'

Original message headers:

Received: from aaaa.namprd20.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::2b76:9]) by aaaaa.namprd20.prod.outlook.com
 ([fe80::2b76:9]) with mapi id xx.xx.xxxx.016; Mon, 10 Jul 2023
 18:12:42 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 10 Jul 2023 18:12:42 +0000
Message-ID:
    <aaaaa@SN7PR20MB5772.namprd20.prod.outlook.com>
Subject: july 10 11:12a
```

This is the code i'm using to send the email

```
$tenantId     = 'a2c7228f';
$clientId     = '0c46e';
$clientSecret = 'peH8';
$userId       = 'bed70475';


$guzzle      = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url         = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token       = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id'     => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope'         => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;


$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);

//send an email

$mailBody = [
    "Message" => [
        "subject"      => Request::post('subject'),
        "body"         => [
            "contentType" => "html",
            "content"     => Request::post('content'),
        ],
        "toRecipients" => [
            [
                "emailAddress" => [
                    "address" => Request::post('to_email'),

                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$response = $graph->createRequest("POST", '/users/' . $userId . '/sendMail')
    ->attachBody($mailBody)
    ->execute();
```

If I manually send the email from Outlook to `12345@gmail.com` it does get sent. Why do my emails from my script bounce? Do I need to do some configuration on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly specific - it means the IP address was tagged as a potential threat to Office.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-the-delist-portal-to-remove-yourself-from-the-office-365-blocked-senders-lis?view=o365-worldwide&redirectedfrom=MSDN